# Why are views getting clipped during scene transition?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, android-transitions

I have a scene transition defined for animating one layout to the other. The entry animation works just fine, while exiting it looks like the views are getting clipped by the bounds of the destination layout. How do I fix that?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val sceneRoot = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.scene_root)

    val fabCompactViewGroup = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_menu_compact, sceneRoot, false) as ViewGroup
    val fabExpandedViewGroup = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_menu_expanded, sceneRoot, false) as ViewGroup

    fabCompactScene = Scene(sceneRoot, fabCompactViewGroup)
    fabExpandedScene = Scene(sceneRoot, fabExpandedViewGroup)

    revealManager = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.fab_reveal_transition)
    dismissManager = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.fab_dismiss_transition)

    currentScene = fabCompactScene

    fabCompactScene?.let { TransitionManager.go(it, dismissManager) }

    fabCompactViewGroup.findViewById<FloatingActionButton?>(R.id.fab_compact)?.setOnClickListener(this)
    fabExpandedViewGroup.findViewById<FloatingActionButton?>(R.id.fab_compact)?.setOnClickListener(this)
    fabExpandedViewGroup.findViewById<FloatingActionButton?>(R.id.fab_expanded1)?.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Expanded 1 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    if(currentScene == fabCompactScene) {
        currentScene = fabExpandedScene
        fabExpandedScene?.let { TransitionManager.go(it, revealManager) }
    } else {
        currentScene = fabCompactScene
        fabCompactScene?.let { TransitionManager.go(it, dismissManager) }
    }
}
```

[FAB Transition GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IC8Z.gif)

Comment: Please, share `R.layout.fab_menu_compact` and `R.layout.fab_menu_expanded` layouts.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of parent `ViewGroup` of animating views. `ViewGroup` by default doesn't draw parts of childs which are outside of parent bounds. To fix it add this lines to parent `ViewGroup` of animating views

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

or programmatically

```
viewGroup.setClipChildren(false);
viewGroup.setClipToPadding(false);
```